# Can someone explain to me how this is possible? (Picture in comments)

Tags: javascript, html, notepad++

So I'm trying to link up my html and javascript files in notepad++, but it isn't working properly.

[image]

I wanted to know how it is possible that it writes test, but doesn't remove the div. Can anyone explain this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're trying to use jQuery without linking jQuery. And you're trying to select an element before it exists.

Comment: Please try to post the code rather than pictures of the code.

Comment: Not sure you want to be writing HTML, etc. within the Notepad++ folder, btw.

Comment: Alright my bad, stupid mistake. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have linked jquery. You're trying to use it without having it linked.

Answer (score 4):

1, jQuery isn't linked. Meaning, you don't have `<script type='text/javascript' src='myjQueryfile.js'></script>` in your HTML, you'll want to put it before your script.

2:
Because the element with the ID of `blue`, doesn't exist yet. The DOM - basically the object of your HTML - has yet to be constructed when your script is run, which in this case is the top of the page, before `blue` comes into existence. You'll want to use an event to fix this, typically `$(function(){ ... });` which will execute your code when the DOM is ready.

Also, `document.write` just writes code then and *there*, meaning exactly where the  `document.write` calls is made, the HTML will be outputted.

Answer (score 0):

The script is loaded in the head. At the time the script executes the body of the document is not built, so nothing is removed. If you were to use the document.ready callback (and had properly included jQuery) it would work

```
$(function(){ $("#blue").remove(); });
```

A plain js version of this is

```
window.onload = function(){ 
 var b = document.getElementById("blue");
 b.parentNode.remove(b);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time the script runs, only the portion of the document up to the <script> tag has been loaded. You need to delay until the DOM has fully loaded before the script can target the DOM:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    $("#blue").remove();
});
```